# Chained methods and continuation indent in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting, indentation, method-chaining

I've never figured out how to make Intellij handle continuation indent for chained methods properly, and apparently today is the day it's annoyed me enough to consult you lovely people.

What I want is this:

```
makeAThing(
  "with",  
  "params"
)
.setProperty("with some more params")
.start();
```

What I get is this:

```
makeAThing(
  "with", 
  "params"
)
  .setProperty("with some more params")
  .start();
```

I get this in Java, Groovy, JavaScript and a bunch of other places.  How can I persuade Intellij not to add continuation indent after a chained method call?

Comment: This comes up a lot when using angular.js, because the convention is to break lines when defining modules.

Comment: We badly need this for `SwiftUI` too in AppCode

Answer (score 3):

I just switched to intellij and also have found this rather annoying.

Only found two solutions:

1. forcing the coding style to have 0 for "continuation indent" which I'm starting to like anyway albeit not very canonical Java.
2. Turing off the formatter for blocks of code and press shift tab

Works for Java not sure for JS:

```
// @formatter:off
...
// @formatter:on
```