# How to stop flattening of fluent APIs in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, indentation, method-chaining

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5 to write Java code that uses fluent APIs and I noticed that when I close a block around a "fluent" portion of code then IDEA automatically flattens the "fluent" code into a single line.

For example, if I have this method:

```
public int sendMessage(Message message) {
  Response response = JerseyClientHelper.target(serverUrl)
            .header("User-Agent", userAgent)
            .post(Entity.entity(message));
  return response.getStatus();
}
```

and I try to wrap it in a new 'if' block, then I would type the if condition and open the block:

```
public int sendMessage(Message message) {
  if (message != null) {
    Response response = JerseyClientHelper.target(serverUrl)
              .header("User-Agent", userAgent)
              .post(Entity.entity(message));
    return response.getStatus();
    // Didn't type the '}' to close the block yet
}
```

but as soon as I type the `}` to close the block, IntelliJ flattens the code into a single line:

```
public int sendMessage(Message message) {
  if (message != null) {
    Response response = JerseyClientHelper.target(serverUrl).header("User-Agent", userAgent).post(Entity.entity(message));
    return response.getStatus();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to disable the automatic flattening of fluent APIs? I've looked in the "Code Style -> Java" and "Code Style -> General" sections but couldn't find anything that would be specifically related to this.

Comment: How come it did not get 769 votes?!! Am I the only one using Stream APIs? ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

settings > code style > java > wrapping and braces > chained method calls

(in version 14)

it looks like this

```
myInstance.call()
          .again()
          .eclipseIsRubbish(true)
          .cestfin();
```

Comment: Oh, "chaining method calls" :) Thanks!

Comment: Although this works it appears that "continuation indent" is too dumb to realize your method chaining so I find myself having to press "shift tab" or "reformat code" when chaining methods.  For now I just set continuation indent to 0 which is annoying also. I'm curious if others have this problem.

Comment: @AdamGent I am using version 14, it works perfrectly ... whereever the first method call starts, each chained call is directly under ... see my update

Comment: @NimChimpsky I'm using 14 and It appears if you have lambda/anon classes as arguments or the first "." is on its own line it gets confused.

Comment: @NimChimpsky see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455513/chained-methods-and-continuation-indent-in-intellij/30168306

Comment: @AdamGent thats javascript, bit different ... they are not methods for one.

Comment: @NimChimpsky See this gist: https://gist.github.com/agentgt/7aa05288b560a6190091. If you have a method (static or not) that takes a anon/lambda and then another one inside it messes up indent on the inner continuation. This happens quite frequently with RxJava and/or Java8 Streams.

Comment: @NimChimpsky Apparently its a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120707

Comment: This is reformatting every sequence of calls, not only fluent APIs. So, for example, person.getAddress().getStreet() also ends up on a new line cause it's a "chain" of calls, even if it's not a fluent API at all.